# why using more than 2 threads consume more time?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to optimize my sequential code to make a gradient.

The main thread compute gradient for the border of the image and the other threads each one compute the gradient for a chunk of the image,
using 2 threads and the main thread give result better than sequential code but using more than 2 threads, but it consume **more** time and looks worst than the sequential.

I tried this code to speed up the gradient process:

```
 for (int n = 0; n<iter_outer; n++)
        {
            int chunk = 1 + ((row - 1) / num_threads); //ceiling
            int start=0;
            int end=0;
            //Launch a group of threads
            for (int tid = 0; tid < num_threads; ++tid)
            {
                start = tid * chunk;
                end = start + chunk;
                t[tid] = thread(gradient, tid, g, vx, vy, row, col, 1, start, end);

            }
            //Launched from the main;
            gradient(1, g, vx, vy, row, col,0, start, end);
            //Join the threads with the main thread
            for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
            {
                t[i].join();

            }

        }
```

Comment: How many cores does your machine have?  Possibly 2?

Comment: Everytime you switch between threads you require time to setup the new context.

Comment: For short running threads, there's a point where the overhead of creating a thread (and switching between contexts) cancels out the speed gain from having multiple threads. I suspect your image is just too small.

Comment: Imagine having 1000 threads - program would have to constantly switch context in order for all threads to get some job, which would increase total time of execution

Comment: To avoid misinterpretation of my previous comment : even if you would be working on a huge image, you would still not see a linear speed increase when adding threads. This is due to the increased overhead of context switching (as pointed out by others). For a given workload on given hardware, you can determine an optimal amount of threads (by guessing and fine-tuning eg.).

Comment: Memory read/write could be a factor too. Depends on what Gradient is doing, but it could cause a lot more thrashing of the CPU mem cache with more threads. Rather than just chunking it roughly by number of threads, try and size all memory processing into 64 Byte chunks aligned on 64 Byte boundaries. Each thread should handle an integer number of these "chunks". Also, many of the values passed to the Gradient function aren't changing between calls. consider putting all the non-variant parameters into a struct, then just sending a pointer/reference to that instead of all the parameters each time

Comment: There is no guarantee that your operating system will delegate one thread to each core and run in parallel.  There is a probability that your threads can run serially on one core (while the other core is running other tasks).

Comment: @NathanOliver : my machine is core i7 and i tried to use 2 threads and 3 and 4 and so on till 14 threads.

Answer (score 4):

For any parallel execution you have to take into account [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law). It states that the time required to do some task in parallel does not scale linear with the number of processors:

```
t = ( (1-p) + p/n ) * T
```

where

```
T is the time needed for the task when it is done sequentially
p fraction of time that can be parallelized
n is the number of processors
```

Note that I used a slightly different formulation, but the statement is the same: The total speedup you get is limited by `1/(1-p)` (e.g. if `p=50%` your parallel version will run maximum twice as fast).

In addition to that you have to consider that adding more parallelism in reality also adds more overhead (for synchronisation, setting up threads, etc), so a more realistic estimate is:

```
t = ( (1-p) + p/n ) * T  + o*p
                           ^^ overhead
```

This `t` as a function of the number of processors `p` has a minimum for a certain number of processors. Adding more processors to the problem will not result in a speedup but rather in a slow down, because the minimum time you need to do that `p` portion is zero, but the overhead you add by adding more processors increases unlimited.

This does not explain why you dont get a speedup in your case, but in general it is not a big surprise that simply adding more processors on a task does not always result in a speedup.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply.
i tried to speed up this code using cuda and gpu and the result is correct and speed up very good and used many threads reached to 256, so i think it's good to be parralelized. but using threads on cpu more than 2 threads like 3 or 4 is worst than sequential !
so i ask, is it normal to be parrallelized on gpu but not good on multithreading of cpu ? and why? if you have example it would be great.

Comment: @islamgad I dont have any experience with cuda. Please note that my answer only outlines the very basics and the details can be much more involved. For example when you have communication between the processors, the overhead can scale as bad as `p*(p-1)`. Also it might be that your problem size is just too small to be efficiently distributed. Threads waiting for others can significantly detoriate your speedup. However, the only reliable way to understand what is going on I know is to measure.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

The parallel execution is a huge benefit for tasks that are easily splittable and the threads will not depend on themselves, however creating threads does come with a price. Let's imagine that a computer does nothing else but running your program (there is not OS and no other processes). The processor has 2 cores, they are processors in their own regard and can concurrently run any code. In case of just one thread the second core sits and does absolutely nothing hence there is potential for speed up. If you spawn the second thread (and give it 50% of the task) the second core now works as well and theoretically the speedup is 2 (ignoring the sequential parts and practical aspects). Now, lets make 4 threads. Wait... we have two processors and 4 threads? Yes, now each CPU does more than one thing and before changing the task on which it works the CPU has to switch contexts (change the values of registers to hold appropriate variables values, go to different code section and so on) this takes time and if you create way too many threads it will in fact take more time than doing the job. This might be a huge impact on any threaded application and should be noted before deciding on how many threads to run.

Note that this post is as simplification many modern CPU's can run efficiently more then one thread per core (ie. HyperThreading).

Comment: HyperThreading does not mean that a modern CPU can efficiently run more than one thread per core; only that they can run more than one thread per core at once. HyperThreading only gains about 15% performance or so - far less than a new core - but more than zero. It is also more complicated as many modern multi-core CPUs runs faster if only a single core is running - since there is less risk of over-heating.

Answer (score -7):

It seems like your CPU is dual-core. So, actually, only 2 tasks could be done parallel

Comment: Complete bogus guesstimate. Besides a dual-core CPU being capable of running more than 2 tasks in parallel (e.g. Hyper-Threading), the real cost here is most likely thread creation. This should be a comment at best.

Comment: my machine is core i7